# What are some examples of 3-dualizable $(\infty,2)$ categories?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, higher-category-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory, extended-tqft

From the cobordism hypothesis, we know that (the space of) symmetric monoidal functors from the $(\infty,3)$ category of framed cobordisms into a symmetric monoidal $(\infty,3)$ category is the same as (the space of) 3-dualizabile objects in the target category (this isomorphism is obtained via evaluation at a point). Therefore, it is of interest to study $3$-dualizable $(\infty,2)$ categories from the point of view of TQFTs. Indeed, $1$-dualizable objects in (derived) vector spaces is the collection of finite dimensional (derived) vector spaces. $2$-dualizable objects in stable infinity categories tensored over $Vect$ is the collection of smooth and proper categories. This is simply the next object in this sequence.

Let $Vect$ be the stable $(\infty,1)$ category of $\mathbb{C}$-modules. Let $2Vect$ be the $(\infty,2)$ category of stable $(\infty,1)$ categories tensored over $Vect$. The question I have is, what are some interesting examples of $3$-dualizable objects in the $(\infty,3)$ category of $(\infty,2)$ categories tensored over $2Vect$?

(This tensored over $2Vect$ is a way to express a generalization of stable infinity categories to higher categorical numbers due to German Stefanich).

I'm also happy to hear about any variations of this question, like $3$-dualizable $(\infty,2)$ categories where the ambient $(\infty,3)$ category is changed, or examples of $4$-dualizable $(\infty,3)$ categories, etc. I imagine there should be many examples from people who study TQFTs, however I am not very familiar with the literature. I am especially interested in examples where the $(\infty,2)$ category has a symmetric monoidal structure. Many thanks.

Comment: Certain(?) fusion monoidal categories give examples of 3-dualizable objects in a suitable 3-category. see here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.7188 . I would guess one can fit these into your framework by considering module categories. I expect somebody will write a more complete answer here soon!

Comment: The general sentiment is it should be extremely hard to come up with any examples for your main question, besides totally discrete examples like the fusion categories Sam mentions. If you allow various target $(\infty,3)$-categories it becomes easy, eg any $E_3$ algebra is 3-dualizable in the Morita theory thereof, something similar should hold for E2-categories,more generally "$\beta$-factorization homology" should allow you to see it's easy for $(\infty,3)$-categories to be 3-dualizable, but these are "secretly" objects of $(\infty,4)$-categories so don't address your more precise question.

Comment: @Ben-Zvi thanks for those examples. I assume there should be some examples which generalize quiver representations? Some particular finite lax limits of 2Vect? But I'm not sure if these examples can support interesting monoidal structures.

Comment: By the way, these module categories over fusion categories one categorical number down would correspond only to finite dimensional separable algebras?